# Preservation of out of scope stack variables with deferred execution

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stack

I confess this question shows a lot of possible misunderstandings about stacks and stackframes. Hopefully I am asking a proper question here.

In C# how are stack frames and the local variables handled for code like the following. What makes these cases interesting is that variable j in StartTasks and variable i in StartTasks2 are both used by Tasks that may well be run after these variables are no longer in scope and after the stack frame they are run in would normally have been popped off the stack.

Also, under what conditions does a local variable like j that is constantly being "recreated" get a brand new memory slot after passing out of scope, as happens in StartTask and where does that local variable live (i.e. stackframe of StartTasks, which means the frame can't be removed, or elsewhere)?

```
void StartTasks() {
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < 10000 ) {
        int j = i;
        Task.Run( () => ExecuteThis( j ) ); // eac
    }
}

void StartTasks2() {
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < 10000 ) {
        Task.Run( () => ExecuteThis( i ) ); // eac
    }
}


void BigBoss() {
    StartTasks();
    StartTasks2();
    NowMakeMoreCalls();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this question shows a lot of possible misunderstandings about stacks and stackframes.

Your understanding is good but you're just not putting all the facts together to reach the explanation. You're 90% of the way there.

Stack frames are an implementation detail. There is no requirement that a local be realized as a stack slot. Remember, what makes a local a *local* is not that it goes on the stack. They're called *local* variables, not *stack* variables. What makes a local a local is that its name is only meaningful inside the method.

> What makes these cases interesting is that variable j in StartTasks and variable i in StartTasks2 are both used by Tasks that may well be run after these variables are no longer in scope and after the stack frame they are run in would normally have been popped off the stack.

First off you have incorrectly used the term "scope". "Scope" is a **compile-time** concept; the scope of a local variable is *the region of code text in which that variable may be accessed via its name*.  You are using "scope" as the **runtime** concept of the lifetime of a stack frame. That's not scope; that's lifetime.

You are correct to note that the lifetime of the local variable is longer than the lifetime of the stack frame. Obviously that means that the local cannot be realized as a stack slot.  It isn't. That local is realized as a field. The field is a field of an object that is referenced by the task.

> under what conditions does a local variable like j that is constantly being "recreated" get a brand new memory slot after passing out of scope

When re-using the slot would create an incorrect program! Re-using the slot is an optimization. The compiler doesn't make optimizations that create incorrect programs.

> where does that local variable live?

If the lifetime of the variable is known to be the same as the lifetime of the stack frame (or less) then it can go on the stack. If not then it has to go on the heap.

Comment: So, Eric, could you suggest a better title? In particular, it would be good if future readers could find this post.

Answer (score 5):

They are elevated to be part of a compiler generated class.

A simple decompilation of what you've provided gives some answers:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass5
{
  public int i;
  public Program <>__this;

  public <>__DisplayClass5()
  {
    base.<>ctor();
  }

  public void <CStartTasks2>b__3()
  {
    this.<>4__this.ExecuteThis(this.i);
  }
}
```

The compiler generates this class and passes a reference to the calling class into it. It also stores the closed over variable as an instance field.

So, to answer the question.. they aren't allocated on the stack. They form an object defined at compile time and instantiated at run time.